# Displaying text like a man page

Tags: c, console

I want to display text from a file named list.txt, and I want it to look like a man page display in Linux using pure c. Text can be scroll up and down, at the bottom there is a line that stays there when the text in the scroll. I do not know what it is called.

What methods can I use to create this with C?

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: Technically you can browse [man sources](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/tree/src) and look for clues.

Comment: Linux and windows.
I will try it.

Comment: man-db source code is too complicated for noob like me :D

Answer (score 2):

A terminal is (on Linux and other POSIX systems) quite a complex thing. Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html). BTW, terminals are unknown to the C11 standard (you should simply consider POSIX; on Windows, things could be even more complex).

You probably should consider using some library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

BTW,  `man` is often from [man-db](http://man-db.nongnu.org/) and that is a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code you can study.

Or you could just run -perhaps using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)- some pager, e.g. [less(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)

Comment: Maybe I will try by using ncurses.
Thanks for this suggestion.